# Enable "Full Keyboard Access" programmatically on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, xcode5.1

I'm developing an app for Mac OS X with Xcode 5 and I need to navigate through the buttons, radio buttons with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

There's a way for navigate between buttons and all other controls by enabling this option in System Preferences:

[image]

…but I need to enable this programmatically for new users which doesn't have this feature enabled. How do I do that?

Comment: I’d still like to see this answered — not to foist it on unsuspecting users, but for scripts like my new computer set-up script that configures similar settings to my liking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out where the preference is stored on disk and change that file, but that is not a good idea. What if the user does not want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through all controls? And the implementation will be fragile: what if Apple changes the name of the plist key in a future release?

A better way is to use the [OS X Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/osx/) so that your app can access the user interface of other apps. (For security reasons, your app needs to prompt the user to enable accessibility through System Preferences.)

Comment: Sorry for the necro-post - but can isee some code implementing this?

Comment: @Kevin Chen: The link you provided is dead.  Can you please provide an update?

Comment: @JS. i couldn't find the same page so i linked to the general OS X accessibility page. the original one is [archived by internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140603023748/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html), though.